# How do I update my database on my windows server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, iis, database-migration

I want to deploy my changes to my server, but I get a error because I made some changes in my database.

> The model backing the 'DbContext' context has changed since the database was created.

I solved this locally by using the *package manager console* in Visual studio user `add-migration` and `update-database`. How should I update the database on my server? I've also added  Automatic Migration to my `Configuration.cs` but this doesn't solve it.

```
 public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... traditionally, you have to run the the Update-Database command against your production database. The command has parameters that allows you to specify the connection string parameters pointing to a specific db:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
[<CommonParameters>]
```

Example:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=MyDb;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose -Script
```

Tip: Use -Verbose and -Script parameters first to make sure that there aren't any problems. That will create only the migration SQL script without making any change to the db. After that, call the same command without the -Script parameters to commit the changes

Comment: Could you give a example of what the connectionString should look like? I'm not sure what exactly I should put there.

Comment: If you look to your xml configuration, in the "connectionStrings" section you will see the production connection string with the attributes "name", "connectionString" and "providerName" (if you use config transfor, just preview the release transform to see the update production connection). You can then use these strings as parameters for the update-database command: Example: Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=MyDb;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose -Script

Comment: Of course, you might need to update the security settings to a privileged DB Account

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong. I put 'Integrated Security' on False en provided a username and passowrd into the connection string by adding: User Id=+username_;Password=_password_". Now I get a error wasn't found or accessible. I already checked if remote connections are allowed using SQL server management Studio. This is the command I'm using: Update-Database -ConnectionString "Server=IP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=false; User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SQLClient -Verbose

Comment: Take out `Trusted_Connection=True`. Then google sql server connection string. Have you managed to connect to your database through SSMS yet?

Comment: You can add (and test) your connection string in Visual Studio using SQL Server Object Explorer. But are you sure you have a SQL Express DB in production?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I haven't. I normally log in with windows authentication so I added a user but I think I'm missing some configuration.

Comment: @IonutUngureanu ye i'm sure. It's currently running. Creating the database the first wasn't a problem, but now that I'm trying to change some tables, I get a error saying the context is different. I'm trying to deploy a new version.

Comment: @IonutUngureanu The model backing the 'DbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: @JasonLie did you made some manual modifications since the first deployment? (directly in the db)

Comment: @IonutUngureanu I have, but only changed some values. Not the structure

Comment: @JasonLie If you deleted data from the __MigrationHistory table then the EF won't be able to make automatic changes. If this is not the case, then probably there are more changes. I would recommend you make a schema compare to see how much the db have diverged.